# Create JS function add to stage

Tags: javascript, createjs

In createjs I'm trying to add elements to the stage but only when called by a function.

If I add this code into my onload init() function the code works:

```
 function init()
{
 background = new createjs.Shape();
 background.graphics.beginLinearGradientFill(["blue", "darkgreen"], [0, 1], 0, 0, 100, 100).drawRect(0, 0, 70, 70);
 background.x = 0;
 background.y = 0;  
 stage.addChild(background);
}
```

However if I add it like

```
function init()
{
loadScreen();
}
function loadScreen()
{
background = new createjs.Shape();
 background.graphics.beginLinearGradientFill(["blue", "darkgreen"], [0, 1], 0, 0, 100, 100).drawRect(0, 0, 70, 70);
 background.x = 0;
 background.y = 0;  
 stage.addChild(background);
}
```

I'm probably just doing something silly, any tips appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Seems fine -- here is a fiddle with your code. Since you are just showing the small part, the demo has some additional code to make it run. http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/LpgddrL1/

Comment: Thanks Lanny, I can see that fiddle is working, it has helped indeed, pointing to that the issue is with the other code in my init function! If you post this as an answer I would like to accept this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your variables are declared.

E.g.
`var stage; var background;`

And make sure that they are global.

```
window.onload = function(){
    var stage;
    var background;

    function init(){
        // create reference to stage and add 'tick' listener.
    }
    function loadScreen(){
        // draw something onto the stage.
    }
};
```

Check out this website for an example: http://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/modules/EaselJS.html.

Comment: All my variables are global so far, but thanks for posting

Comment: Hi @berni, Thanks for responding, I've fixed the issue now, a createjs grid I built was causing the issue, it wasn't closed properly, its rectified now. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the semicolon(;) after loadScreen() function defenition

```
function init()
 {
  loadScreen();
 }
 function loadScreen()
 {
   background = new createjs.Shape();
    background.graphics.beginLinearGradientFill(["blue", "darkgreen"], [0, 1], 0, 0, 100, 100).drawRect(0, 0, 70, 70);
    background.x = 0;
    background.y = 0;  
    stage.addChild(background);
```

}

Comment: Hi Anoop, thanks for answering. There is no (;) after the function definition, only after the call to the function.

Comment: @StephenKennedy but you have given semi-colon(;) after function

Comment: function loadScreen();
{
background = new createjs.Shape() see ; after loadScreen in your code?

Comment: Ah Apologies, you are correct, thanks for pointing that out, actually in my actual code that mistake doesn't exist which is why I couldn't see it.

Answer (score 1):

I can see that you removed this line ->

```
 myGraphics.beginLinearGradientFill(["#000","#FFF"], [0, 1], 0, 20, 0,   120).drawRect(20, 20, 120, 120);
```

Have you tried instantiating background inside init() and then passing the object to the load function?

Comment: Hi Alberto, thanks for the response. I have tried that indeed, for some reason if the stage.addChild(background) is in the loadScreen() function it causes the program to crash, but if the stage.addChild is in the init function it runs fine, its driving me mad

Comment: I would suggest to revisit the way you are declaring the variables. Maybe "stage" is not global and it's scope is limited to init() - and it's parent -. That would cause it to fail if you invoke it in loadScreen().